# Embed/Insert module (code) into Joomla template

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I have recently came across a tricky issue with a Joomla installation. The idea is that I can't upload any other component, module etc; just templates.

Thus, because I can't upload one of the modules my menu is based upon, I am asking you if there's a way I can just grab the code from the module itself and insert it into the template directly?

How should I modify (or what part of the module code should I modify) to make it work with the template directly?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Better to solve the root cause of the problem than try to hack around it and store up more problems for the future. What error do you see when you try to add a module? Are you installing it through the admin interface? Are you FTP'ing a zip file to your live server?

Comment: You can upload modules, components etc using the Install/Uninstall feature?

Answer (score 0):

Following on from your comment:

> The setup is provided by the government. No FTP access or anything. It
>   just denies me uploading modules. Only templates

OK, that's the real problem: you've been put in a situation where you can't really do what you being asked to do, presumably by the same people who are imposing those restrictions. That is, quite frankly, ridiculous. However, if you really MUST do what you're suggesting, I would:

- warn them that this is really dangerous, brittle, and far more of a problem than them giving you the access you require would be
- go ahead and embed the module code in your template, but be aware that you'll need to do this in a development environment *first*, and you'll need to tweak quite a few things (e.g. parameters - how customisable is this module?)

I **really** think that this is the wrong way of going about it, though; there may even be aspects of the module that make this impossible, but that's difficult for me to say.

Answer (score 0):

If the server is set up optimally to run Joomla, you should not need FTP access in order to install extensions. You will want to have PHP run in CGI mode, which tends to be more secure anyway. Then you should be able to install extensions without the FTP layer.

As Bobby Jack mentioned, it can probably be done another way, but it's going to me a lot more work and trouble than doing it correctly.